# How do programs add to $PATH variable with using .bash_profile?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, path

How do some programs seem to add to the $PATH variable without using a .bash_profile file? What are the advantages to these approaches of adding to $PATH variable, but not using a .bash_profile file?

For my mac

`echo $PATH` returns

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

`which java` returns

```
/usr/bin/java
```

`which tex` returns

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/tex
```

How is Java available in the terminal without being in the $PATH variable? (This is an example of something running in the terminal without being in the $PATH variable.)

How did TeX add to the PATH variable without using a .bash_profile file?

What added Library/Apple/usr/bin to the PATH variable? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) says that only the first three are defaults: /bin, /usr/bin, and /usr/local/bin.

Note: Other StackOverflow posts helped users create a .bash_profile file (a file that doesn't exist by default on a Mac) to run programs such as android and adb when they received `-bash: android: command not found`
My question is about how the terminal works (like how java is running without being on $PATH) and how other programs (like TeX) added to $PATH without using a file like .bash_profile.

I am running macOS 10.15.5, confirmed that I do not have a .bash_profile file, do have homebrew installed (not sure if that affects anything) and when I open a terminal, it says "The default interactive shell is now zsh." (I think I installed zsh after reading a different StackOverflow a few weeks back.

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/653803/how-does-mac-os-x-set-the-value-of-path

Comment: and https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/OSX/path_helper.html